# Check input for 4 numbers and 2 letters with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I have a text `<input>` with  `maxlength="6"` but I want to check if the first 4 characters are numbers and the last 2 are letters.

I have this code:

```
$("input[id='post']").keyup(function count() {
   //what goes here?
});
```

but I really don't know how to go on further.

Comment: try `keypress ` instaed of `keyup`

Comment: Define "numbers" and do you expect only latin letters?.

Answer (score 4):

You can use RegEx to do this

```
$("input[id='post']").keyup(function count() {
    var input = this.value;
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}$/i);
    console.log(regex.test(input));
});
```

`[0-9]{4}` - Checks for four digits between 0-9.

`[a-z]{2}` - Checks for two letters between a-z. The `i` flag at the end makes the check case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Something like:

```
$("input[id='post']").keyup(function count() {
    var valid = /^\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/.test(this.value);
});
```

so that `valid` will be `true` if the input matches your condition, and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This will log `Valid` to console if it matches the required pattern:

```
$('#post').keyup(function() {
    if (/^\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/.test(this.value)) {
         console.log("Valid");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like this `^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}$` and make a `key up/down` function to use it

See this link from to test the usage

[Demo Testing and regex explained](http://regex101.com/r/dY9nF3)